# Access variables in a php file attached to controller method in codeigniter

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

Thanks all.
I am using an a payment api that I supply with a callback URL so that I receive data to notify my system and update payment as "paid". The api posts raw json data when successful with details of the transaction which I save in a realfile.php.

realfile.php is as below:

```
<?php 
$post = file_get_contents('php://input');  
$data = json_decode($post); 
$reference=$data->reference; 
$reason=$data->reason;  
?>
```

My callback URL is like this:

```
 http://localhost/index.php/controller/method/realfile.php
```

My Question:

How do I access variables `$txid, $reason, $reference` from the URL to as to mark my payment as complete in my controller method???

Thanks a lot.

Comment: you already have  $reference=$data->reference; $reason=$data->reason; that code is not working?

Comment: Hello Max Phoenix Newbie, What is your api response?

Comment: It's raw json object. {"key":"value"...}

Answer (score 0):

So, if you supply the URL to the payment api, then I think that is where you are making your first important decision. You said that your callback URL is:

```
/index.php/controller/method/realfile.php
```

But with CodeIgniter, depending on your configuration, you could have simply had the URL as:

```
/index.php/realfile
```

This would have allowed you to create a Realfile.php controller with the following contents:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Realfile extends CI_Controller 
{
    public function index()
    {
        $post      = file_get_contents('php://input');  
        $data      = json_decode($post); 
        $reference = $data->reference; 
        $reason    = $data->reason;

        // Actually, you have access to anything that is inside data:
        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump( $data );
        echo '</pre>';
    }
}
```

By doing that, you'd have complete access to all of CodeIgniter's core classes, libraries, helpers, database, etc.

Comment: Thanks so very much... I will try this... Since my reputation is still below 11, my upvote won't appear publicly but I have upvoted you... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I actually wasn't getting results with `file_get_contents('php://input')`... So I read the documentations and came across this:

`$this->load->helper("security");

```
    $stream = $this->security->xss_clean( $this->input->raw_input_stream );

    $data = json_decode(trim($stream), true);`
```

I can now access `$data` as an associative array.
And that worked really well...
Thanks for the controller idea